# Change datetimepicker format in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys i am trying to compare the `date` from my database and the date range i select from my datetimepicker. It is unable to compare because the format of both differ from one another. The `date` in my database has the format of `YYYY-MM-DD` while the format from the datetimepicker is `MM-DD-YYYY`. I am trying to convert the format of the datetimepicker to match with the format in my database. How can i accomplish this??

```
{!! Form::input('date', 'endDate', null, ['id' => 
'datetimepicker','class' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'yy/mm/dd']) !!}

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
   dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
</script>
```

**Format in datetimepicker**

[image: format in datetimepicker]

**Format in database**

[image: format in database]

Comment: if you are using jquery ui datepicker then you can use `dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"`

Comment: @Ash-b im not too sure if its jquery ui or bootstraps ui datepicker... do u mind helping me check? i have updated the codes and yes i have already tried using `dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" it doesnt work

Comment: @linktoahref hi may i know where should i put that line of code in? and i would like  to change to `YYYY-MM-DD` not `MM-DD-YYYY`.

Comment: @DexterSiah you included css and js file for datetimepicke. plz paste that included file here not files inner code only included file.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya i dont have any included css or js file. I have only included  `bootstrap-datepicker.css` and `bootstrap-datepicker.js`in my header for the datepicker function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either change the date format of the datepicker you are using

or

You could create a carbon instance from the date obtained and compare that with the one from database.

For the second condition, in your controller where you get the date, you could do

```
$form_date = $request->form_date;
$database_date = Carbon::parse('2018-07-01');

$form_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $form_date);

// Change Format
$form_date_string = $form_date->format('Y-m-d');

// Comparisons
$form_date->gt($database_date);
```

[More Comparison Docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison)

Comment: For the second option, the changes would only be changed at the backend of comparison am i right? it does not actually change the format of actually datetimepicker. Correct me if im wrong

Comment: Yes it does the change only in the backend and does not affect your front end

Comment: how to do it for the date picker itself (first condition) ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```

Comment: remove data-date-format from Form input and then try this.

Comment: nope... still not working am i missing something? is this the correct way `{!! Form::date('date', 'startDate',['id' => 'datetimepicker','class' => 'datepicker']) !!}`